# Logits and labels must have same shape for Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Keras and have been practicing with resources from the web. Unfortunately, I cannot build a model without it throwing the following error:

> ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 1)).

I have attempted the following:

```
DF = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/master/tutorials/MAGIC%20Gamma%20Telescope/MAGIC%20Gamma%20Telescope%20Data.csv")

X = DF.iloc[:,0:-1]
y = DF.iloc[:,-1]
yBin = np.array([1 if x == 'g' else 0 for x in y ])
scaler = StandardScaler()
X1 = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, yBin, test_size=0.25, random_state=2018) 

print(X_train.__class__,X_test.__class__,y_train.__class__,y_test.__class__ )

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6,activation="relu", input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))
model.build(input_shape=(None,1))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=X_train,
          y=y_train,
          epochs=600,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )
```

I have read my model is likely wrong in terms of input parameters, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly mentioned by @MSS, You need to use [`sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) activation function with 1 neuron in the last `dense` layer to match the `logits` with the `labels(1,0)` of your dataset which indicates binary class.

**Fixed code:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6,activation="relu", input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
#model.build(input_shape=(None,1))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,epochs=10,validation_data=(X_test, y_test),verbose=1)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
446/446 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5400 - accuracy: 0.7449 - val_loss: 0.4769 - val_accuracy: 0.7800
Epoch 2/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4425 - accuracy: 0.7987 - val_loss: 0.4241 - val_accuracy: 0.8095
Epoch 3/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4082 - accuracy: 0.8175 - val_loss: 0.4034 - val_accuracy: 0.8242
Epoch 4/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3934 - accuracy: 0.8286 - val_loss: 0.3927 - val_accuracy: 0.8313
Epoch 5/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3854 - accuracy: 0.8347 - val_loss: 0.3866 - val_accuracy: 0.8320
Epoch 6/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3800 - accuracy: 0.8397 - val_loss: 0.3827 - val_accuracy: 0.8364
Epoch 7/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3762 - accuracy: 0.8411 - val_loss: 0.3786 - val_accuracy: 0.8387
Epoch 8/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3726 - accuracy: 0.8432 - val_loss: 0.3764 - val_accuracy: 0.8404
Epoch 9/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3695 - accuracy: 0.8466 - val_loss: 0.3724 - val_accuracy: 0.8408
Epoch 10/10
446/446 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3665 - accuracy: 0.8478 - val_loss: 0.3698 - val_accuracy: 0.8454
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f68ca30f670>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the shape of your data

```
print(X_train.shape,X_test.shape,y_train.shape,y_test.shape)
```

I see, that `X` is 10-dimensional and `y` us 1-dimensional

Therefore, you need 10-dimensional input

```
 model.build(input_shape=(None,10))
```

and 1-dimensional output in the last dense layer

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation="softmax"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Target variable `yBin/y_train/y_test` is 1D array (has a shape (None,1) for a given batch).

Your logits come from the Dense layer and the last Dense layer has 10 neurons with softmax activation. So it will give 10 outputs for each input or (batch_size,10) for each batch. This is represented formally as (None,10).

To resolve the particular shape mismatch issue in question change the neuron count of dense layer to 1 and set activation finction to "sigmoid".

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
```